# Show event for all Bootstrap Modals on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to do something (in this case some statistics) whenever a Bootrap modal is opened.

I know, I can ad an event listener like this to a modal:

```
$('#modal-content').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   alert('do something');
});
```

But is there a way to have a listener for all modals on the page? Bonus question: even for those who are inserted by Javascript?

I have thought about something like this:

```
jQuery('.modal[role="dialog"]').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
   alert('do something');
});
```

But I hope that there's a better way and something that will work for modals that are inserted by Javascript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This ought to do the trick for you--it catches the event when it bubbles up to the document level, so that should catch them all:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   alert('do something');
});
```

See [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/wYEE6Jr03y)

HTH,
-Ted

Comment: Nice one! Exactly what I was hoping for!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ids ahead of time, you could just list them out:

```
$('#modalOne, #modalTwo').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   alert('do something');
});
```

Or better yet, if you are creating them programmatically as well as in html and are using a common prefix for the id, you can use the following:

```
$("div[id^='modal']").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   alert('do something');
});
```